# How unwindForSegue:towardsViewController: works?

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

In my simple app, I have created some controllers with basic segues between them:

**Yellow controller -> BlueController -> GreenController -> OrangeController**. Every of them has its own custom class.

From **OrangeController** I created unwindSegue to my **YellowController**. It is ok.

Within every class I put:

```
override func unwindForSegue(unwindSegue: UIStoryboardSegue, towardsViewController subsequentVC: UIViewController) {
    print(unwindSegue)
    print(subsequentVC)
}
```

But it was not called at all. Why? What demo should I prepare to test this functionality?

The same is with:

```
func allowedChildViewControllersForUnwindingFromSource(source: UIStoryboardUnwindSegueSource) -> [UIViewController]
func childViewControllerContainingSegueSource(source: UIStoryboardUnwindSegueSource) -> UIViewController?
```

Comment: "I have created some controllers with basic segues between them" Yes, but _what_ kind of controllers are they and what kind of segues are they? `unwindForSegue` is called only on _parent view controllers_. If you made nothing but modal (presentation) segues, for example, it won't be called at all, because unwinding consists entirely of simple dismissal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implement the method with `IBAction` returnType

```
-(IBAction) unwindForSegue:(nonnull UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue towardsViewController:(nonnull UIViewController *)subsequentVC
```

In `Storyboard`, link the control *(which is responsible for the back action)* to the exit action in the viewcontroller.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the difference between normal 'unwindForSegue'?

Comment: From meaning perspective `IBAction` is same as `void`. The big difference is that interface builder can *see* IBAction methods. I don't know if compiler leaves *breadcrumbs* for every IBAction method or Interface builder re-parses source code looking for IBAction methods only however it is certain that Interface builder requires IBAction methods for unwind segues. For other simpler stuff like buttons actions it is not required anymore https://nshipster.com/ibaction-iboutlet-iboutletcollection/