# Proper way to transit between two screens programmatically in iOS. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have `ViewController.swift` files associated with storyboard (I use it for admob set up). 
My UI is written in `viewDidLoad` function in each viewController class.
I have created segues in storyboard and use this code:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueName", sender: nil)
```

Here is the problem. If I move between two screens back and forth, somehow the number of elements on the screen multiplied by two. I manage to find this due to this error:

```
Attempt to present VIEWCONTROLLER1 on VIEWCONTROLLER2 whose view is not in 
the window hierarchy!
```

First time I back to the screen there is only one error. Next - 2, 4...  Soon enough (back and forth between screens) delay becomes incredibly long like 15 seconds and doubles with each transition.

What is the problem and how to work around? Every time I move to the next screen remove all subviews on the previous?

Comment: where you call self.performSegueWithIdentifier ?

Comment: from buttons action functions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're recreating each VC each time you segue. From VC2, you need to call:

```
self.unwindForSegue("segueName", towardsViewController: FirstVC)
```

See also: [UnwindForSegue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31499406/how-unwindforseguetowardsviewcontroller-works)

Comment: If I want to be able to move back and forth between 2 screens I need 2 "just segue" and 2 "unwind segue"? And somehow use "just segue" for first transition and "unwind segue" when it is not first?

Comment: Your code does not compile. The error is `VC2 does not have a member named 'unwindForSegue'`